# Unable to send any messages to Kafka using spring kafka producer - Timeout exception

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Environment :
spring-boot.version - 1.5.9.RELEASE
spring-kafka.version - 1.2.0.RELEASE
Kafka instance's client lib version - kafka-clients-0.10.2.0.jar

In Kafka spring application , unable to send any message from producer to kafka instance

```
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s)
 for testtopicname-0: 60018 ms has passed since last append
```

I have increased timeout property also but that didn't help either

Few of producer config props :

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 60000);
props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 3);
props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 1);
props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 5);
```

Snapshot of Code to send message :

```
kafkaTemplate.send(message)
```

Following is SSL specific config

```
Kafka Instance :

ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.client.auth = none
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLS
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS

Spring producer : 

ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLS
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
```

Comment: I think I've see something similar if you try to send non-SSL to SSL and vice-versa. Do your client and server SSL configs match?

Comment: @GaryRussell , I have added ssl specific config in description.        The only additional config there is in kafka instance  ssl.client.auth = none and I tried putting this in producer config like props.put("ssl.client.auth", "none") and when i run app i see following warn 

2018-06-06 09:43:43.464  WARN 14240 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : The configuration 'ssl.client.auth' was supplied but isn't a known config.


The overall result doesn't change, the original problem still persists.

Comment: Try enabling DEBUG logging for `org.apache.kafka` on the client to see if it gives you any clues; all I can say is I have seen this with mismatched SSL configs.

Comment: if it cannot connect to the brokers you get the timeouts